# Color with lines

Tags: java, android

I want to set color in my app to example red with black lines, something like this:

[image]

How can I get this ?

You know, I have condition, if something is wrong i want set the color with lines, else just color.

Comment: You should post here the image and not hosting it outside so we are sure is not going offline

Comment: i puted image on stack hosting, but i don't have  15 reputation

Comment: Simply **tile** a single red square with a diagonal black line, as @Abhi suggested.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve diagonal lines background, simply create a single small line in Paint or Photoshop. Save it within the Drawable folder.

Now create an XML drawable.

**diagonal_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/DiagonalLine"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:dither="true"
>
</bitmap>
```

In your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="your_color"
>

<ImageView 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/diagonal_background"
android:visibility="gone"/>   <---- set it to gone and call it under an if-else statement

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

You could set the background of the View from drawable using this:

```
layout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.diagonal_background));
```

Comment: i can't do this, I paint on canvas, so i dont have layout, i can just change a color

Comment: Check the edited answer. If the issue still persists, add the relevant code as an edit in the question.